# Displaying more than one content in a cell in asp.net

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a cell and want to display 'hello' in the middle and if some condition is true then display 'world' at the right bottom of that cell.

Here, Only hello and world is getting displayed but 'world' not at the right bottom.

```
tc.InnerHtml = "Hello";
if(some condition)
{
                    Label lblBundle = new Label();
                    lblBundle.Style.Add("font-size", "5px");
                    lblBundle.Style.Add("float", "right");
                    lblBundle.Style.Add("float", "bottom");
                    lblBundle.Text = "world";
                    tc.Controls.Add(lblBundle);

}
```

Can anyone please help me out. I am displaying the label control dynamically.

Comment: You're not adding the Label to the cell.

Comment: I added, but i want it in the right bottom. What should I do ?

Comment: float: bottom isn't a thing. You might want to google around a bit about vertically positioning HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to append just word to existing content than why you need to add label. try following:

tc.InnerHtml = tc.InnerHtml + " world"